# Try to do cin >> string[array] and there is an error (""string subscript out of range")

Tags: c++

The code :

```
class DataBase {
private:
    int age, stuNumNew;
    string stuName, command;
    string ver = "Alpha";
    float stuNum = 1;
public:
    void Start() {
        cout << "Welcome back to Sudent DataBase <ver " << ver << ">." << endl;
        cout << "Type 'Add' for add a student.";
        cin >> command;
        if (command == "Add") {
            Add();
        }
        else if (command == "Search") {
            cout << "Student number: ";
            cin >> stuNumNew; //Get input from user
            cout << "Name: " << stuName[stuNumNew] << endl << "Age: " << age[&stuNumNew] << endl;
            Start();
        }
    }

    void Add() {

        cout << "Name: ";
        **cin >> stuName[stuNum] * *; //get the name
        cout << "Age: ";
        cin >> age[stuNum]; //get the age
        cout << "Student Number: " << stuNum;
        stuNum = stuNum++;
        stuNumNew = stuNum;
        Start();
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you think `cin >> stuName[stuNum]` does? Since, currently, you are trying to read in a `char`, and write it into the `stuNum`th position of `stuName` (and the error implies that `stuNum`th character in `stuName` didn't exist)? Did you want to create a `std::string` array, and read in elements of that?

Comment: It seems you assume all types can be treated as containers. For example, there is no way `age[stuNum];` is meaningful. It's odd to use ` float` as an index, you should be using an integral type. `Start()` and `Add()` call each other recursively, limited only by user input. This will inevitably crash if the user chooses to continuously add new students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) allow you to create variable size arrays

The issue you're having is caused by using a fixed size variable. What you need in this case is a `vector` because what you are trying to do is assign names and numbers to arrays that are of variable sizes so that you can add new students in your program.

Vectors allow you to do just that.

**Here is the modified code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class DataBase {
  private:
    int searchInput;

    /* declare a vector of type int to contain your students' ages */
    vector<int> studentAges;
    /* declare a vector of type std::string to contain your students' names */
    vector<string> studentNames;

    string command;
    string ver = "Alpha";
    /* stuNum is removed because vectors keep track of their own sizes */

  public:
    void Start() {
      cout << "Welcome back to Student DataBase <ver " << ver << ">." << endl;
      cout << "Type 'Add' to add a new student or type 'Search' to search the database of students." << endl << " > ";
      cin >> command;
      if (command == "Add") {
        Add();
      } else if (command == "Search") {
        /* You may want to build in a conditional that checks if there are any students yet. */
        cout << "Student number: ";
        cin >> searchInput;

        if (searchInput < studentNames.size()) {
          /* Make sure that the users input (the number) is actually a student's id number
           * otherwise reject their input to keep the program from crashing or having undefined behavior.
           */
          cout << "Name: " << studentNames[searchInput] << endl << "Age: " << studentAges[searchInput] << endl;
        } else {
          cout << "Student number invalid" << endl;
        }
      } else {
        /* Tell them if their input is invalid */
        cout << "Invalid option." << endl;
      }
      Start();
    }

    void Add() {
      /* Append new positions for input */
      studentNames.push_back("");
      studentAges.push_back(0);

      cout << "Name: ";
      cin >> studentNames.back();
      cout << "Age: ";
      cin >> studentAges.back();

      /* The student number is the newest index of the vector */
      cout << "Student Number: " << studentNames.size() - 1 << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  DataBase d;
  d.Start();
}
```

You can also combine your variables `studentNames` and `studentAges` into a `students` vector if you create a class (or struct) that keeps both values together:

```cpp
class Student {
  public:
    Student(string name, int age) {
      this->age = age;
      this->name = name;
    }

    string name;
    int age;
};
```

Then you can use it with `vector`:

```cpp
vector<Student> students;
```

**NOTE:**

You may want to add some input protecting because if you enter a string where it wants a number it breaks the program.